# Accessing https://35.198.218.44/ via Chrome

Tags: google-compute-engine

I subscribed to a VM and Static IP address is 35.198.218.44

I ssh into vm via cygwin.  Local port forwarding works fine.  i could ping vm and get response from my computer

I am trying to browse via Chrome by giving https://35.198.218.44/ or https://35.198.218.44:8888

I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in return

Not sure why this happens.

Tried the remedies posted in web, but nothing works

Comment: What say output from command `ss -l | grep 443` and `ss -l | grep 8888`? Witch app listen for connection on this ports?

Comment: did you install a web server in your VM? type `sudo netstat -nap |egrep '80|443'` and show it here

Comment: @2707974 I get no output on ss -l | grep 443 but got out for ss -l | grep 8888 as tcp    LISTEN     0      128                  *:8888                  *:*

Comment: That mean you do not have service that listen on port `443`. On `8888` you have service Process/app that running on `8888` you can see with command `ss -lp | grep :8888`.   I can connect to port `8888` Output  `nc -v 35.198.218.44 8888
Connection to 35.198.218.44 8888 port [tcp/*] succeeded!` but cannot connect on port `443`. Output `nc -v 35.198.218.44 443
nc: connect to 35.198.218.44 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I opened up port 443 and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the ports 443 and 8888 are closed at your VM. The following command can show the firewall rules.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Comment: I get following output                                                         NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY
default-allow-http      default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80
default-allow-https     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22

Comment: It looks like you have a server on port 8888, but that port is not open. Port 443 (https) is open, but you don't have any server listening there. Open port 8888 as described at https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I opened up port 443 and that worked